# If you did not want to use Cocos2D, or a similar framework, how would you start making a game like "The Legend of Zelda" part 1 for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am going to make a 2D iPad game today, but I do not want to use a game framework. I am more interested in how the framework is created, how to program the physics, and other low level topics.

So, if I'm not using a framework, how do I start? Is the first step to create an OpenGL based app in XCode?

Comment: This looks far too general to be usefully answered.  It might also be more on topic at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL would be a place to start, but i would look through the cocos2d source, and see how various things are being done in that.

Answer (score 0):

To program a 2D game from the ground up, especially if you're new to iOS, I don't see any reason to use anything other than the CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation APIs. Any bitmap-based imaging is typically done via OpenGL behind the scenes.